# Get file name from commit message in git

Tags: git, commit-message

In git some days back (Around 1 month) i pushed wrong files to repository with a commit message 'Test' . 
In local system i want to see those files with commit message 'Test' in a particular branch .How to check ?

Answer (score 1):

First you can try searching through the Git log to find commits matching the text `Test`:

```
git log -g --grep=Test
```

Then you may view the files in a given commit using this:

```
git show --pretty="" --name-only 7dj82lb3
```

where `7dj82lb3` is the SHA-1 hash of the commit whose commit message matches your search text.